# Webpack/Karma/awesome-typescript-loader Won't Ignore Files

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, karma-jasmine, angular2-aot

I use Webpack 2.x to compile my Angular 2 App. For production code I use a combination of `ngc` and `@ngtools/webpack`'s AotPlugin for compilation. For testing I use `awesome-typescript-loader`. The production build of my code works just fine. However, when I do an `npm test` something very strange happens... `awesome-typescript-loader` complains that it failed to compile the code, but Karma runs through the tests anyway and they all pass.

```
bash-3.2$ npm test
> btc2017@1.0.0 test /Users/tomb/Projects/brandontom.com/wp-content/themes/btc2017
> NODE_ENV=test node ./node_modules/.bin/karma start --single-run=true

webpack: wait until bundle finished:

[at-loader] Using typescript@2.2.1 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from /Users/tomb/Projects/brandontom.com/wp-content/themes/b
tc2017/tsconfig.json.
[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...
[at-loader] Ok, 1.054 sec.
ERROR in ./ngfactory/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
Module parse failed: /Users/tomb/Projects/brandontom.com/wp-content/themes/btc2017/ngfactory/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts Unexpe
cted token (65:56)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import * as import55 from '@angular/router/src/router_config_loader';
| import * as import56 from '@angular/router/src/router_state';
| class AppModuleInjector extends import0.NgModuleInjector<import1.AppModule> {
|   _CommonModule_0:import2.CommonModule;
|   _ApplicationModule_1:import3.ApplicationModule;
 @ ./bootstrap/main.aot.ts 1:0-78
webpack: Failed to compile.
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Mac OS X 10.12.3): Executed 4 of 4 SUCCESS (1.41 secs / 0.758 secs)
```

That's a neat trick, but I'd rather skip trying to parse that file in the first place, especially since that file is generated.

My first thought was to ignore the directory that file gets generated in. It gets constructed in a folder called `ngfactory`. Here's the rule that I've added the following rule to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
  test: /\.ts$/,
  loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
  exclude: [/(node_modules|bootstrap|prebuild|ngfactory)/]
}
```

But `awesome-typescript-loader` keeps trying to parse this file despite the `exclude`. Next I thought it might be Karma that was pulling this in so I added an exclude rule to my `karma.conf.js`.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  var _config = {
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      { pattern: './karma-shim.js', watched: false }
    ],
    exclude: [
      'bootstrap',
      'dist',
      'ngfactory',     // <--- here's where that file lives
      'node_modules',
      'prebuild'
    ],
...
...
```

When I removed the artifact folders (`prebuild` and `ngfactory`) I realized that the bootstrap file (which lives in a directory called `bootstrap`) was being parsed and that file was trying to import `app.module.ngfactory.ts` I added `bootstrap` to the various `exclude` properties (including my `tsconfig.json`). Still, nothing stopped the issue from arising. If anyone has seen anything like this, I'd love to know how you got around this.

Here's my full `webpack.config.js`:

```
var neat = require('node-neat')
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin

var sassPaths = neat.includePaths.map(function (path) {
  return 'includePaths[]=' + path
}).join('&')

module.exports = (function (nodeEnv) {
  var config = {
    entry: {
      globals: [ 'core-js/client/shim.min', 'reflect-metadata', 'zone.js' ],
      main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bootstrap') + '/main.aot.ts'
    },
    devServer: {
      inline: true
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
        { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'raw-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?' + sassPaths, exclude: /node_modules/ }
      ]
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
        __dirname
      ),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        process: { env: { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv) } }
      })
    ]
  }
  if (nodeEnv !== 'test') {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
    })
    config.plugins.push(new AotPlugin({
      tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json'
    }))
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      mangle: { screw_ie8: true, keep_fnames: true },
      compress: { screw_ie8: true, warnings: false },
      comments: false
    }))
  } else {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
      exclude: [/(node_modules|bootstrap|prebuild|ngfactory)/]
    })
  }
  return config
})(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "outDir": "./prebuild",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./ngfactory",
    "entryModule": "src/app/app.module#AppModule"
  }
}
```

For good measure, here's my `karma.conf.js` as well:

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config')

module.exports = function (config) {
  var _config = {
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      { pattern: './karma-shim.js', watched: false }
    ],
    exclude: [
      'bootstrap',
      'dist',
      'ngfactory',
      'node_modules',
      'prebuild'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './karma-shim.js': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    webpackMiddleware: {
      stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    progress: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    color: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_ERROR,
    browsers: ['Chrome']
  }
  config.set(_config)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I wasn't able to stop `awesome-typescript-loader` from compiling artifacts, I was able to get it to stop failing whenever it did. The loader has a boolean setting called `transpileOnly`. Setting this to `true` prevents the loader from doing type checking. I added it to my `tsconfig.json` in the `awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions` section.

This isn't ideal, but I'm okay (for now) with `awesome-typescript-loader` not enforcing type checking on the testing side... I guess... So long as `ngc` does enforce it on production code.

Here's my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "outDir": "./prebuild",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true,
    "transpileOnly": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./ngfactory",
    "entryModule": "src/app/app.module#AppModule"
  }
}
```